# VB.NET include .exe in project and attach to main process

Tags: vb.net, process

I have a VB.NET project (main.exe) and include an additional .exe application as internal resource. Now I do not want to run the extra .exe as a separate process but want to attach it to the process of main.exe so I have just 1 process overall and not 2.

Can this be done somehow?

Thanks

Comment: What is the nature of the additional .exe?  Is it another .NET application?

Comment: additional exe was written in C++ for functionality that VB.NET does not provide.

Comment: would be grateful for some pointers...thx

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to compile the additional.exe as .dll and use it in VB.NET